# Receiving `Got unexpected send receipt for message` warning when using `SendAsync` method on Pulsar producer

Tags: go, publish-subscribe, apache-pulsar

I have a Pulsar topic to which I am publishing messages through multiple producers. These producers are just goroutines and I am using `SendAsync` method on a producer to send messages but I keep getting `Got unexpected send receipt for message` warning. I looked into the client's library code (golang client for Pulsar) and found that this warning can show up only when the producer is not registered as a listener in this map `map[uint64]ConnectionListener`. But, how am I able to publish when the producer is not registered as a listener?

```
func benchmarkConcurrentProducers(b *testing.B, pool []pulsar.Producer, concur int, payload []byte) {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(concur)

    for i := 0; i < concur; i++ {
        go Produce(pool[i], payload, wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func BenchmarkProducer(b *testing.B) {
    type config struct {
        Pulsarcfg struct {
            Url string `required: "true"`
        }
    }
    cfg := &config{}
    err := configor.Load(cfg, "../config.yml")
    require.Nil(b, err)

    client, err := pulsar.NewClient(pulsar.ClientOptions{
        URL:               cfg.Pulsarcfg.Url,
        OperationTimeout:  30 * time.Second,
        ConnectionTimeout: 30 * time.Second,
    })
    require.Nil(b, err)
    defer client.Close()

    concur := 4

    producerPool := make([]pulsar.Producer, concur)

    for i := 0; i < concur; i++ {
        p, err := New(client, string(i))
        require.Nil(b, err)
        defer p.Close()

        producerPool[i] = p
    }

    path, err := filepath.Abs("../events.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("invalid payload file path, %v", err)
    }
    f, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("bad payload: %v", err)
    }

    b.Run("benchmark producer", func(b *testing.B) {
        // run the producer b.N times
        for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            benchmarkConcurrentProducers(b, producerPool, concur, f)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be two reasons for a producer to be not registered as a listener in `map[uint64]ConnectionListener`. Either, the producer was never created or the producer got closed. In my case, I was able to publish messages that means the producer was indeed created but since I was using `SendAsync` method to send messages it didn't block to receive the acknowledgement. And, I was using `defer` to close a producer after producing all the messages(I did use a `wait group` to make sure all the messages are sent before closing the producer) but producer got closed before receiving the acknowledgement and hence, the warning.

Comment: Can you post the code example? As you already said earlier, the connection listener map is tracked by the producer Id. Can  you trace the producer Id in the log?

Comment: @MingL. I have added the code and yes I was able to see the producer Id in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error message. In my case I created a reader and a producer using the same client. Although the reader was already closed when I was producing new messages, I kept receiving this warning, and even worse, it would hang on the call to `producer.Send()`. I solved this by using separate clients for reading and for producing.